# acts_as_votable , undefined method `upvote_by' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, vote

i am trying to user acts_as_votable gem to make user vote for stars

this is my stars-controller

```
class StarsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
    before_action :upvote 
    def index
        @stars = Star.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

  def upvote 
   # @star = Star.find(params[:id])
   @star.upvote_by current_user
   redirect_to @star
  end

    def show
        @star= Star.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
    end

    def create
        @star =Star.new(stars_params)
        @star.save

        redirect_to @star
    end




    private 
    def stars_params
        params.require(:star).permit(:name , :description , :image)
    end

end
```

and this is my star model

```
 class Star < ActiveRecord::Base


has_many :books

has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :small => "150x150>" }
validates_attachment_presence :image
validates_attachment_size :image, :less_than => 5.megabytes
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']
acts_as_votable
end
```

and the routs

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :books

  devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}

  resources :stars do 
    member do 
      put "like" , to: "stars#upvote"

    end
  end


  root 'stars#index'
end
```

i get this error "undefined method `upvote_by' for nil:NilClass"

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not really related to `acts_as_votable` - your instance variable has not been assigned yet, so practically any method would cause this error. You have to un-comment commented line and change:

```
before_action :upvote
```

to

```
before_action :upvote, except: :index
```

This logic however seems fishy - why would you like a star to be upvoted when user is editing it? In short: please clarify your requirements.

Comment: thank you but when i edit eh before_action as you said , a new error in star model 
undefined local variable or method `acts_as_votable' for #<Class:0xb52a7500>

Comment: Have you restarted the server after installing this gem?

Comment: Yes , i restartedt the server

Comment: Hmmm, weird. Method should be there as long as gem is installed. How did you installed the gem?

Comment: i re-installed the gem and it works correctly :) 
thank you :)